# How to use NgRx Store in a Router Guard?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

Similar questions have been asked but none solution worked for me.
The state of my Store is:

```
export interface AuthState {
  isLoggedIn: boolean,
  ...
}
```

I would like to use that `isLoggedIn` in the router guard so I have something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private store: Store<fromAuth.AuthState>) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.canNavigate();
  }

  canNavigate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(AuthSelectors.selectIsLoggedIn).pipe(
      filter(isLoggedin => isLoggedin), // issue comes from here
      tap(isLoggedId => {
        if (!isLoggedId) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then()
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

This code works well when a user just logged in but not work when we reload the application and don't have a token locally. After reloading the app, I have a blank page because the `filter()` method is stuck.

I implemented an `autoLogin()` method which dispatch an action to set the `isLoggedIn` to true in the store when we reload the app, it works but same problem when there isn't a token.
The question is how to by-pass the `filter()` and redirect to the login page when we `isLoggedIn` is false?

**EDIT**

This is the code of the `autoLogin()` method:

```
autoLogin() {
 from(getTokenFromLocalStorage()).pipe(
  tap(token => {
    if (token) {
        this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.autoLogin({payload: token}));
     }
   })
).subscribe();
```

}

Then in the `reducer` I update the `isLoggedIn` field.
`autoLogin()` is used in the AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("App start");
    this.authenticationService.autoLogin();
  }
}
```

@brunoj's answer suggests to remove the `filter()` function, I can't do it because the `AuthGuard#canActivate()` method is executed before the reducer, so before the update of the `isLoggedIn` field. `filter()` permits the waiting for the update in the reducer.

Comment: The `filter` method seems to be filtering out any false values. So your later `if` will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

Like DeborahK said filter operator is filtering every isLoggedin falsy value.
You jusst need to remove filter operator from your stream. When your stream will have false value navigation will be canceled and your tap operator will be executed and user will be redirected to login page.

Comment: I can't remove the filter operator, see the edit.

Comment: you should have some routes that doesn't need to be guarded by the guard. I guess in this example it is the login page. So if user is not logged in he should be redirected to that page. Then in your login page you need to redirect user to the page that you want **after** token is already saved. For example you can create effect that redirect user to some page after autoLogin action is dispatched. Basicly you need to  Something like that is explained in this tutorial:

https://medium.com/upstate-interactive/create-a-login-feature-with-ngrx-in-6-steps-8691395bcda7

Comment: I already handled the case regarding the login process. Now I would like to handle the case where the user refresh the application. I would like to keep him in the same page if he is logged. I am going to try something different and let you know if it works